# evt argument inside a function in javaScript

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, addeventlistener, predefined-variables

### evt argument inside a function in javaScript

Hello stackoverflow community.
I need to know how is the **evt** argument used in these functions.
There are some examples in the internet which have the argument evt inside of a function, but I don't see them using the argument.

```
document.getElementById("creator").addEventListener("click", function(evt){
    alert("created");
});

document.getElementById("change").addEventListener("click", function(evt){
    alert("changed");
});
```

I guess the evt argument is just set as undefined because those functions are never called with a value for the argument.

- So what is the reason for setting the argument variable evt?
- can it be hello instead of evt?
- if it is predefined to the event listeners, how can I find a list of
  predefined arguments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When an event is invoked, it will be passed an event object as it's first argument.  You can name `evt` whatever you like.  Common names are `e` `evt` and `event`.

I typically use this for things like

`event.preventDefault()` Stop an events default action, on submit for example.

and

`event.target` Find the tagret of the element the event was invoked on.

There are a lot more properties that can be used on the event object, and becomes very useful if you know how to use it.  More information about event object here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event